# Thumbnail / image screen shot for video

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an App which allows the user to play a selection of videos.

What I would like is to have one or two thumbnails shown on my view which shows the user that if they click on these images it will launch a video.

How do I capture a screen shot from the video to use as an thumbnail or do I have to user some other random image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption` with an `MPMoviePlayerController`.
You can also request to fetch multiple Thumbnails asynchronously (`requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption:`). In that case you have to register an observer for the `MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification`.